# how to shrink an array if two consecutive numbers in an array are equal then remove one and increment other

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, array-reduce, array-pointer

How to shrink an array if two consecutive numbers in an array are equal then remove one and increment other

Example 1:

```
int a[6]={2,2,3,4,4,4};

// Output: 6
```

Example 2:

```
int b[7]={1,2,2,2,4,2,4};

// Output: {1,3,2,4,2,4}
```

Comment: What should be output of `[5, 5, 5, 1]` ?

Comment: [6,5,1] is output for [5,5,5,1]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in near-linear time like so:

```
a = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4]
c = [5, 5, 5, 1]

def shrink_array(a):
    res = []
    
    for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
        if i < len(a) and a[i] == a[i-1]: # if equal to previous
            a[i] += 1 # increment and move on
        else:
            if len(res) > 0 and res[-1] == a[i-1]: # if equal to last in res
                res[-1] += 1 # increment last in res
            else:
                res.append(a[i-1]) # add to res

        while len(res) > 1 and res[-1] == res[-2]: # shrink possible duplicates
            res[-2] += 1
            del res[-1]
        
    return(res)

for arr in [a, b, c]:
    print(shrink_array(arr))
```

**Output:**

```
[6]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4]
[6, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [2,2,3,4,4,4]
    
def shrink(lst):
    idx = 0
    while len(lst) > idx+1:
        a, b = lst.pop(idx), lst.pop(idx)

        if a == b:
            lst.insert(idx, a+1)
            idx = 0
        else:
            lst.insert(idx, b)
            lst.insert(idx, a)
            idx += 1

shrink(lst)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[6]
```

---

For `[5, 5, 5, 1]` prints `[6, 5, 1]`

Comment: once check the code for 67,67,65,65,66,66,66,68,67,67,65,65,66,70